The type or namespace 'UI' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'
Im working with a MAUI application. dotnet version 8.0
Im unable to resolve this error
Does anyone have any idea on how to resolve the below
The type or namespace UI does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'
I tried installing Microsoft.UI.Xaml nuget package
but things didnt work

You can put the code in the #if WINDOWS #endif. The namespace is only used in windows platform.

According to the error message, you need use Conditional compilation to target Windows platform. In other words, platform code can be invoked from cross-platform code by using conditional compilation to target different platforms:
#if WINDOWS

Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window window = (Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window)App.Current.Windows.First<Window>().Handler.PlatformView;
IntPtr windowHandle = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(window);
...

#endif


